# Copy files (of specific extension) from a folder structure to another folder

Tags: linux, shell, copy

I am confused to how to copy a specific type of files from a folder structure to simply a folder on a **LINUX** machine.

This is how the source folder structure is:

```
Folder_X
    file1.type
    file2.nottype
    - Folder_Y
        file3.type
        file4.nottype
        - Folder_P
            file5.type
            file6.nottype
            - Folder_A
                file7.type
                file8.nottype
    - Folder_Z
        file9.type
        file10.nottype
```

So When I do `find . -iname "*.type"`  in **Folder_X**, I get following output

```
./file1.type
./Folder_Y/file3.type
./Folder_Y/Folder_P/file5.type
./Folder_Y/Folder_P/Folder_A/file7.type
./Folder_Z/file9.type
```

I want to copy these `.type` extension files to another location in a single folder as this

```
/some/another/location/Folder_I
file1.type
file3.type
file5.type
file7.type
file9.type
```

Any help is appreciated... Thank you for time

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code,

The find command has a -exec option. 
ref : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html

```sh
find . -iname "*.type" -exec cp {} /some/another/location/Folder_I \;
```

Comment: also, you may try `cp "$(find . -name '*.type')"  /path/to/your/destination`